# Why does slightly different url cause ASP.NET MVC OAuthWebSecurity cause user to register again?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

We have an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Azure Websites.  We are using the OAuthWebSecurity provider to allow for users to login to the site.  Basically the stock stuff when you do File -> New in VS2012 for a ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet application.

We've now registered for a custom domain, so intead of `yoursite.azurewebsites.net` you can access it via `yoursite.com`.  Of course, you can also use `www.yoursite.com`.  If I login and register using `yoursite.com`, and then visit `www.yoursite.com` it causes me to have to re-register.  Why is that and how does one fix it?

So If I had subdomains, i.e. `area1.yoursite.com` and `area2.yoursite.com` it would also cause the user to register again.  I'd like to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not due to ASP.NET but depends on which external provider you are using.  Each has its own configuration options and (in)flexibility.

Google is the most "convenient" requiring zero set up on any site with any name (and gives you the email address of the user automatically in addition to the Open Id).

Microsoft account and Twitter are the toughest making it almost impossible to use during development when your site name is localhost with a port number other than 80.  Microsoft is under the misguided notion that a domain name must consist of at least two words separated by a dot and that all web sites operate on port 80.  Hence `JUPITER` or `localhost` are not permitted as site names. However, once you have a valid Redirect Domain in your settings, Microsoft accounts will work for all sub-domains of that Redirect domain. So if your Redirect domain is `yoursite.com`, `www.yoursite.com` will also work.

Facebook is somewhere in the middle where you can easily specify the domains for a particular App Id.